# How to add scrollbar in SSRS Subreports inside tablix cell?

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

Below is an image of how I wants to show report.

[image]

Gray area in the image is subreport. When it returns list of too many employees it  applies scrollbar to webpage. As per requirement page should not scroll but only the list of employees.

Can anyone help how can I make subreport to scroll?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no direct way in SSRS to achieve this. But after some research this can be done..

Whenever SSRS report renders on page it converts it into table structure. So I was trying to apply css to tablix cell in which my subreport is placed. I applied tooltip to tablix inside subreport, when it renders tooltip is converted into Title attribute. here you go... find the element with title attribute in jquery already on your page. and then apply the css from jquery.

I tried with id property but, ssrs always generates a new random id for elemnts in reports... that did not work but the tooltip or title property in html surely works.

thanks to jquery selectors...